# how to show the content of other websites in my website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I am looking for a code which does a simple task. below is the task

let's say my site is http://www.url.com

I want when my user go to this site they see a box on top of the page which shows my site name and also my contact details and also a countdown timer.

below this line I want to show the exact same website of few different URL and I want to set a timer as well so that these few websites rotate and that timer on top shows how long it is until the next refresh and next website. I want only this part of the webpage to refresh and I want the top line to be still.

http://i58.tinypic.com/s6t84h.jpg

you can see what I want in the image above.

I was told that it can be done using iframe but I don't know how to do it and I also don't want scroll

I appreciate if you could help me

I found this solution and it seems to be working. I just need the countdown timer and also I want to crop out let's say 200px of top of each website and like shift it up because one page doesn't show all the content I want unless using scrolling and I don't want that.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <div align="center" style="border:4px solid red ">
    <div style="color:#0000FF">
    <h3>some content<color:#0000FF/h3>
<h3>some more content<color:#0000FF/h3>
</div> 
</div>

<iframe id="rotator" src="http://www.zcast.ir" width="100%" height="600" scrolling="no" border="0" ></iframe>

<script>
// start when the page is loaded
window.onload = function() {

var urls = [
"http://www.zcast.ir",
"http://www.tgju.org",
"http://www.on3.ir", 
"http://www.goldinfo.ir",
"http://www.zarban.ir",
];

  var index = 1;
  var el = document.getElementById("rotator");

  setTimeout(function rotate() {

    if ( index === urls.length ) {
  index = 0;
}

el.src = urls[index];
index  = index + 1;

// continue rotating iframes
setTimeout(rotate, 5000);

}, 5000); // 5000ms = 5s
 };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `seamless` attribute to hide borders and scrollbars in `iframe`

Comment: You can use iframe but it can be denied by target site. See my answer and demo for further details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103134/how-to-show-the-content-of-other-websites-in-my-website#answer-23103544

Comment: I updated my question. could you please answer it now

Answer (score 1):

Yes absolutely you can do that using iframe

1) set iFrame `scrolling` attribute to `no`:

```
<iframe src="/default.asp" width="200" height="200" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

read more: [iFrame attr (w3Schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_iframe_scrolling.asp)

2) `setTimeout` for the timer: - [see more](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)
3) Reload the iframe from parent window - [see more](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?64667-how-to-force-an-iframe-to-reload)

You can use style `position:fixed;` and `top:0;` to place the div on top of your page:

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:0;"> some content here </div>
```

so thats it! :)

Comment: when I use <div style="position:fixed;top:0;"> some content here </div>    only the "some content will show and the rest disappears

Comment: Yes of course, you need to do some customizing (styling) into that element. eg: <div style="position:fixed;top0;width:100%;height:100px;background-color:blue;"> Some of content here </div>

Comment: I updated my question. could you please answer it now

Answer (score 1):

You can use iframe but, be sure that target website may disallow iframe embed. You can use following code;

```
var websites = new Array(
    "http://www.hurriyet.com",
    "http://www.milliyet.com",
    "http://www.amazon.com"
);
var counter = 0;
var sTimeOut = setInterval(function () {
    var index = counter%(websites.length);

    $("#website_div").html($('<iframe src="' + websites[index] + '" width="500" height="500" border="0" scrolling="no"/>' ));
    counter++;  
}, 5000);
```

Put your websites in list, and it will rotated.

Here is a working demo: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/83WuH/)**

Comment: thank you for you ranswer. it works just fine. but I have two questions. first how do I write some simple text or content on top and make it fix, I mean in the demo you sent there are four windows which one of them says HTML. I want to know what should I put there. and second how can I add a timer on top so that it shows how many more second the iframe refreshes. I also want to know how can I get the final code from that JSFiddle site.

Comment: is it possible to set the iframe size with percentage so that depending on the device or resolution it changes?

Comment: It is not four windows, it is jsfiddle structure. You can see actuall demo here http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/83WuH/show/ . You can set exact size in `website_div` and make iframe width and height 100%

Comment: I updated my question. could you please answer it now